# How roaming a queue using for?

Tags: c, for-loop, search, queue

I want to check all the elements of the queue, i tried this way, but it does not work.

```
void search_queue(Queue* f) {
    for(i = f->first; i!=NULL; i->next) {
        printf("_");
    }
}
```

I need acess values of "number" of all pages in my queue

```
    typedef struct page{
    int number;
    struct page* prox;
}Page;

typedef struct queue{
    Page* first;
    Page* end;
}Queue;
```

P.S: sorry for my bad english

Comment: We need more informations. How  is `Queue` defined ? What is the type of `i` ?

Comment: `i->next` ==> `i=i->next`

Comment: I need acess values of "number" of all pages in my queue

typedef struct page{
    int number;
    struct page* prox;
}Page;

typedef struct queue{
    Pagina* first;
    Pagina* end;
}Queue;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your code correctly, you pass a `Queue` call `f` that has reference to the start and end of the queue. From there, your goal is to print the numbers of the elements in the queue from start to end. The way you have implemented your queue, it looks as though it's just a simple traversal through a linked-list.

```
void search_queue(Queue* q){
    if(q == NULL){
        /* If queue is empty */
        return;
    }
    Page* current = q->first;
    while(current != NULL){
         printf("%d",current->number);
         current = current->prox;
    }
    return;
}
```